# How do you change the weather?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm a bit confused if you can or can't change the weather on minecraft pocket edition

Comment: [silly answer]: Pudge controls the weather - take him a peanut butter sandwich

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the weather?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/283622/how-can-i-change-the-weather)

Comment: Agreeing with the votes to close this as a duplicate of [How can I change the weather?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/283622/4797). While this question is older and more popular (26k views vs 1k views), this question's answers are outdated.

Answer (score 2):

Weather has not yet been implemented in Minecraft Pocket Edition. It will possibly be implemented in 0.11.0, according to [the wiki](http://minecraftpocketedition.wikia.com/wiki/Update_0.1x.0). From the page on Snow:

> [Snow] is unrenewable as **weather has not been implemented yet** [...]

A mod released in March of 2014 attempts to mimic weather. [Here](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-pocket-edition/mcpe-mods-tools/1987116-minecraft-pe-0-8-1-rain-snow-mod) is a link to the post on the Minecraft forum.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment it isn't possible yet but it will come in a future update.

Of course there are always mods to do this for you and you might even create one yourself and learn a bunch of stuff about Java and Graphics.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Rainbolt's answer, there are also no commands in Minecraft PE so the weather would not be able to be changed anyway.

Comment: Most of the features are changed via settings and not commands (but not weather as of yet) So when they do implement weather it will most likely be a switch in the options/settings.

Answer (score -2):

No, you can't at the moment (August 2015).

I think they're going to enable it in the future though - it's going to be cool.

Comment: I don't think you've quite gotten the hang of answering to the best extent, but that's okay. Please see the other two answers to figure out how you should answer next time.