# How can I change the weather?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm playing on MCPE v15.6.0 and I don't know how to change the weather. How can I change the weather?

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, you can't so far without commands. I would advise using a plug-in or waiting until commands come to move. They are probably coming in update 0.16.0, so not long to wait!

Answer (score 1):

If you're playing a version of Minecraft PE prior to 0.16.0 you cannot. If you are playing MCPE 0.16.0 or later there are [two commands which allow the user to change the weather](https://mcpehq.com/faq/can-change-weather-minecraft-pe/).

- **/toggledownfall** - the toggledownfall command starts or stops precipitation depending upon it's current state. In cold biomes, the precipitation is snow whereas in warm biomes the type of precipitation is rain.
- **/weather** - the weather command allows the user to explicitly set the weather to clear (no precipitation), rain (or snow in cold biomes) or thunder (thunderstorm in warm biomes or thunder snowstorm in cold biomes). Optionally, the length of time the weather should persist for can be set in seconds.

For either of the methods to work cheats must be enabled.